# How use colorbox on fotorama plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox, fotorama

I'm trying to use the fotorama plugin with the data-nav='thumb' with a colorbox on the big image. It seems work, but I can't give a width or an height at the color box.

That's is my code:

```
<div class='fotorama' data-nav='thumbs' data-width='100%' data-ratio='700/467' data-max-width='100%'>
    <div data-img='my_img' class='img-responsive' alt=''>
        <a class='color-box'  href='link_to_my_img'></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.color-box').colorbox({ maxWidth: '10%', maxHeight: '10%', rel: '.color-box', current:''});
});
</script>
```

I've set to 10% to see better the size of the image, but this one is still too big. There is a solution to take the control of the colorbox?

Thanks!!